# Displaying a view controller from a PhoneGap plugin

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm building a PhoneGap plugin that displays the Aviary photo editor (https://github.com/AviaryInc/Mobile-Feather-SDK-for-iOS).  I have a couple working examples using Aviary standalone, but I'm having trouble getting the view controller (AFPhotoEditorController) to display from within a PhoneGap plugin (CDVPlugin subclass).

I'm not sure if there is something fundamentally incorrect in my approach, or if this is just an idiosyncratic part of PhoneGap.  Here's the code that is currently inside of the plugin.  When it executes, nothing happens.  The view doesn't display, there are no errors/exceptions, no log messages.

```
AFPhotoEditorController* aviary = [[[AFPhotoEditorController alloc] initWithImage:photoImage] autorelease];
[aviary setDelegate:self];
[super.viewController presentViewController:aviary animated:YES completion:nil];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I created a simplified sample project that demonstrates the problem https://www.dropbox.com/s/yxiuvkvjnow5r0y/AviaryPhoneGapPlugin.zip

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
[self presentViewController:aviary animated:YES completion:nil];
```